# Go Replay output-http-track-response not returning responses for few transactions

Tags: go

I am trying to log requests and responses data to a file, but not able to get responses for few transactions.

Below is the command:

*./gor --input-raw :80 --input-raw-track-response --output-file %Y%m%d.log --output-file-append*

Thanks,
Surya